# WebClient.DownloadFile is taking way too long before sending the first request

Tags: .net, proxy, webclient

I have written a very simple console application which is just downloading a file using the following piece of code:

```
System.Net.WebClient web = new System.Net.WebClient ();
web.DownloadFile ("http://www.google.com", "file.txt");
```

On my previous development machine, this was very fast. As soon as I executed the `DownloadFile` method, the request went over the wire and the response came back very soon. I inspected this behaviour with the ProcMon tool.

However, after switching to another machine, which happens to be much more powerful than my initial development box, I noticed that nothing would happen for about 5-8 seconds, when calling into `DownloadFile`. Going to the same URL with a browser would show almost immediate results.

After spending several hours looking into this, stepping into the .NET source code, I finally gave up in `System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint` where the stepping somehow no longer made sense to me, and where some proxy resolution seemed to be in cause.

I finally turned off *Automatically detect settings* in the *LAN Settings* dialog of the the *Internet Options* dialog, found in Internet Explorer 8 (I am running Windows 7 x64), leaving the dialog with no checkbox set. This magically made everything do very, very fast. No more delay.

Well, I've found a way to circumvent the problem I was observing, but I'd be glad if somebody could share some ideas as to what might be wrong with my code. Can I somehow achieve the same effect by somehow configuring the `WebClient` instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried explicitly setting the proxy?

```
web.Proxy = new WebProxy();
```

That should basically be equivalent to saying, "Don't use a proxy at all - don't even try."

Comment: as always, you amaze me! You were right, adding an empty WebProxy instance does the trick. I never imagined that the proxy property provided by .NET would be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried setting the web.Proxy properties?

Ex:

```
System.Net.WebClient web = new WebClient();
web.Proxy = new WebProxy("Address here");
web.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com", "file.txt");
```